# How large is the face of a 2x2 45º brick?

Tags: piece-information, size, slope

I am attempting to make a decal for a roof tile, sort of like the computer face on certain bricks of the type. However, as there appears to be no template, how large is the face of a 2x2 45º brick?

Answer (score 5):

The sloped face of the 2x2 brick is 16mm across by about 11.3mm tall.

[image]